# DBCC CHECKDB last good date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dbcc-checkdb, ola-hallengren

SQL Server 2014 Standard.

Using Ola's (blessings be upon him) scripts to perform database integrity checks:
Job command:

```
sqlcmd -E -S $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(SRVR)) -d master -Q "EXECUTE [dbo].[DatabaseIntegrityCheck] @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @LogToTable = 'Y'" -b
```

I know, I know. Running from master!!!! V, v, v naughty boy. Getting customer to create admin database and move all there. It just takes time ...

All runs fine. Then I run Brent Ozar's (blessings be upon him too) sp_Blitz which tells me that no CHECK DB has been run against some , that's right - not all, just some, databases. What the ...

So, check Command Log table and all looks good:

```
Command                                         CommandType StartTime       EndTime         ErrorNumber ErrorMessage
DBCC CHECKDB ([<Db_name>]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY DBCC_CHECKDB    2018-02-10 15:16:24.100 2018-02-10 15:16:27.033 0       NULL
```

Run DBINFO and all does not:

```
DBCC DBINFO () WITH TABLERESULTS
```

Results:

```
DBINFO STRUCTURE:   DBINFO @0x00000000198CD2E0  dbi_dbccLastKnownGood   2014-07-26 00:10:11.437
```

In confirmed that:

- the database is not readonly
- DBINFO was run against errant database

What gives gurus?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the database was being refreshed from another non-checked database post DBCC and pre sp_Blitz job so all stats externally maintained were out.